# Blog post URL redirection in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

Recently we included blog title along with ID in blog URL. For example,
The old URL:

```
www.domain.com/blog-details/12
```

The modified URL:

```
www.domain.com/blog-details/12/title
```

Now I want to redirect the old blog URL to the modified blog URL in laravel website, if we click old blog URL, it should redirect to the new blog URL.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redirects ?

Comment: 1. Have you changed routes?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a route to handle `www.domain.com/blog-details/12`, fetch the right blog title and then redirect.

If you're able to use [model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redirects) something like this should do the job

```
Route::get('/blog-details/{blog}', function (Blog $blog) {
    return redirect("/blog-details/$blog->id/$blog->title");
});
```

Otherwise you can fetch the blog item by yourself and then redirect

```
Route::get('/blog-details/{id}', function ($id) {
    $blog = Blog::findOrFail($id);
    return redirect("/blog-details/$blog->id/$blog->title");
});
```

You can read more about redirects here; https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redirects

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. currently, my route for is like:
Route::get('blog-details/{id}/{title?}', 'ShowBlogController@getBlogDetailsData')->name('blog-details');

Answer (score 0):

You can use rewrite URLs with .htacess Apache or .conf Nginx

Comment: Bad idea. Web server doesn't know dynamically added database titles. Has to be done in PHP code.